# error when deleting in sqlite database

Tags: sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

Im new in terms of coding, So I copy paste the codes of some tutorials, but when Im trying to delete all data in the "sleep" column, this error is showing.

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "20170128": syntax error
>   (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM 20170128
>                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
>   Method)
>                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
>                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
>                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
>                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.delete(SQLiteDatabase.java:1496)
>                                                        at jm.myapplication.Sleep.sleep_repo.delete1(sleep_repo.java:51)
>                                                        at jm.myapplication.Main.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:220)
>                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
>                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

This is my codes.

This is on my main activity

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                final Integer newSleep = sleep;
                    sleep_repo repo = new sleep_repo(MainActivity.this);
                    others sleep = new others();

                     sleep.sleep = Recent_f_id;
                     sleep.sleep=newSleep;

    repo.delete1(sleep);

    Recent_f_id = repo.insert(sleep);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            newSleep + " has been added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
    d.dismiss();
 }
```

while this is my sleep_repo.java

```
public void delete1(others sleep) {

        // db.delete(String tableName, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs);
        // If whereClause is null, it will delete all rows.
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase(); // helper is object extends SQLiteOpenHelper
        db.delete(getDateTime(),null,null);
        /*db.delete(getDateTime(),others.KEY_ID+"=?",new String[] { String.valueOf(sleep) });*/
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }
```

while this is my others.java

```
public class others {

    // Labels table name
    public static final String TABLE = "others";

    // Labels Table Columns names
    public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_sleep = "sleep";
    public static final String KEY_smoke = "smoke";
    public static final String KEY_exercise = "exercise";





    // property help us to keep data
    public int Recent_f_id;
    public Integer id;
    public Integer sleep;
    public Integer smoke;
    public String exercise;


}
```

and this is my Dates.java

```
public class Dates extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    //version number to upgrade database version
    //each time if you Add, Edit table, you need to change the
    //version number.
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;



    public static String getDateTime() {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyyMMdd", Locale.getDefault());
        Date date = new Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = getDateTime();

    public Dates(Context context ) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //All necessary tables you like to create will create here

        String CREATE_TABLE_meals = "CREATE TABLE " + meals.TABLE  + "("
                + meals.KEY_breakfast + " TEXT, "
                + meals.KEY_lunch + " TEXT, "
                + meals.KEY_dinner + " TEXT, "
                + meals.KEY_other   + " TEXT )";

        String CREATE_TABLE_drinks = "CREATE TABLE " + drinks.TABLE  + "("
                + drinks.KEY_alcoholic + " TEXT, "
                + drinks.KEY_water  + " INTEGER )";

        String CREATE_TABLE_others = "CREATE TABLE " + others.TABLE  + "("
                + others.KEY_ID  + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,"
                + others.KEY_sleep + " TEXT, "
                + others.KEY_smoke + " INTEGER, "
                + others.KEY_exercise   + " INTEGER )";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_meals);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_drinks);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_others);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`20170128` is not a valid table name. (Unless enclosed in square brackets or quotes, table name cannot start with a digit).

Comment: I realize my error, which is 

db.delete(getDateTime(),null,null);

whichh must be 

db.delete(others.TABLE,others.KEY_sleep,null);

But thanks for your answer, Because of your answer, I wont realize my error. I will also keep in my mind your answer. Thanks bro!